# Entity Framework 6 - App Crash - what could appear in Memory Dump?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, crash

In Microsoft ADO.NET Entity Framework Step by Step (By John Paul Mueller),
https://books.google.com.au/books?id=_bVCAwAAQBAJ&pg=PT532&lpg=PT532&dq=%22memory+dump%22+ef+entity+security&source=bl&ots=8m43srh2Em&sig=c3TzdDNPQr3mFMvA70CwGvKgEiw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjEy4qKv6vMAhVSz2MKHdR5CqIQ6AEIJzAC#v=onepage&q=%22memory%20dump%22%20ef%20entity%20security&f=false

he says that that an attacker could force a crash by requesting an abnormally large result set. And then that if the app crashes, an attacker can read sensitive app information from the memory dump.

He does not say what info could be read from the memory dump.

If I have sensitive data (from an encrypted database) in my Entities in the EF context (static for performance reasons), and the app crashes, what data could be in the memory dump?

Comment: The author does say that connection and password information could be accessible.

Comment: I think he meant from the SQL Server connection. I was more concerned with the data in the tables

Comment: Well, any of the data that gets loaded into memory could then be subject to inspection in a memory dump.